# 'the_content' filter removing html tags from post content

Tags: filters, html, the-content

I have a post content(html) like this:

```
<div id="home_tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
<p><a class="jqbut" href="#">read more</a></p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</div>
<div id="tabs-3">Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti.</div>
</div>
```

When I'm using `echo $post['post_content'];` or `echo do_shortcode($post['post_content']);` the content shows up fine. But when using `echo apply_filters('the_content', $post['post_content']);` some of the html tags are removed from the post. The output is like this:

```
<a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
<a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
<a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
<p><a class="jqbut" href="#">read more</a></p>
Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.
Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti.
```

How to get the exact html contents of the post using the content filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting arbitrary HTML into post content, instead use shortcodes! Shortcodes were intended for this situation.

Otherwise you face 2 problems:

- Filters will escape your content via the `wp_kses_post` on output
- TinyMCE will filter/mangle/strip tags when you use the visual editor, even for the slightest of moments

All of these are done for security purposes, content should only contain content, not layout or UI. If you need those, use widgets, or put shortcodes inside your content.

Comment: Thank you. That's the information I needed. If I put the HTML contents in shortcode/widget, then I wont have the ability to edit it through the TinyMCE visual... am i right?

Comment: If you add code in the TinyMCE Text tab, it will still mess with it when you switch back to the Visual tab. Depends exactly what you're adding though.

Comment: Yes, @TimMalone is right. You would need to stick with one tab. Bottom line: avoid `HTML` in TinyMCE as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. My problem (as stated in the question) is (already) using with the TinyMCE text tab.... In context to this answer, I just wanted to know whether I can visually alter HTML in widgets/shortcode when I can't place it in TinyMCE.